# FB Messenger - How to get around the extreme photo/video compression resulting in poor quality?

Tags: video, images, facebook-messenger, file-sharing

I often send photos/videos to my friends on Messenger. The problem is that FB's algorythm compresses them so badly it really affects their enjoyability. I send HD videos, and they get something like it was 2000. I send high quality photos of a document and they can barely read it.

- Is there a way to turn off image and video compression in Facebook Messenger?
- If not, is there any app/extension for sharing original quality images and videos that is convenient to use both for me and the receiver?

Comment: Are you sure it's just Facebook? Most phone carriers transparently compress photos and videos you download over mobile data.

Comment: @Dan Hulme I use a tablet without SIM card. It's definetly not the carrier... :] And they look equally crappy on desktop afr\ter I send them.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but I've found that attaching a picture rather than taking it in-app results in a far better quality result on Messenger's servers. If you take a picture with your default camera app (which stores it locally), and then use Messenger's 'picture' icon to attach it (rather than using the 'camera' icon), the resulting link to FB's CDN containing the picture gives you a file ~50% bigger than the in-app version. Still seriously compressed, mind you.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not really a solution, more so a workaround, but as I got no answers for 3 years, I decided to post it.*

While I think messenger got better lately, it still compresses every media. It's no surprise - they have to store them on their own server after all. But there are a lot of messaging apps that store all media on the recipient's phone instead. Most of these send all media uncompressed, or at most compressed in a barely noticeable way, and they have the additional benefits of generally being much more private and secure than Messenger. Some I used for a longer time are:

- [WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/?lang=en) - it's very widely used everywhere in the world. Used to be renowned for its privacy, but recently [there have been issues](https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2021/03/06/stop-using-whatsapp-after-facebook-apple-imessage-signal-and-telegram-privacy-backlash/) regarding that as Facebook made modifications. It sends all media without any compression.
- [Signal](https://signal.org/en/) - it's a new one, but already gained widespread usage comparable to WhatsApp. Most of the users changed from WhatsApp as Facebook made those privacy-violating steps. (In fact, the week that happened, they had so many new users they temporarily had to shut down the service as the servers couldn't keep up.) It is by far the most private one, as the whole service including the app and the server is completely open-source. Especially used in areas where privacy is more of a concern, like the USA, troubled areas like Hong Kong, or non-democratic countries, but it is gaining popularity everywhere.
- [LINE](https://line.me/en/) - I used it on a daily basis, and among all these, it feels the most "premium". I like the interface, and the stickers and themes are, while paid, are of exceptional quality. Out of all, it's the closest to Messenger in terms of features. Mostly widespread in the Eastern-Asia region, especially in Japan.  It also has an interesting backstory: originally it was created by the LINE corp. for internal usage after the Fukushima accident, to let the employees spread and gain information quickly. Then it proved useful and more and more outside people requested to join, so eventually it became public.
- [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) - I haven't used this too much, but it is roughly on the same level as Whatsapp used to be before the disputed steps of Facebook.
- [KakaoTalk](https://www.kakaocorp.com/page/service/service/KakaoTalk?lang=en) - I barely know its existence, but I list it for completeness. Just as LINE, it's mostly used in Eastern Asia.